# Seed MongoDB Data - Only Once?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm a bit new to the concept of seeding.

My goal is to have a set of data in the database that can be shown on the front end. I don't want to "Seed" the database each time I start the server. I simply want to add one set of data. I've figured out how to seed the database but only if I seed it each time I start the server. Am I going about this correctly? How do I only seed it once? Thanks! I run the `seedfoods()` function in app.js when the server starts.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Food = require("./models/food");

function seedfoods() { 
//add the foods to the database
data.forEach(function(seedfoods){
Food.create(seedfoods, function(err, Food){
if(err){
console.log(err)
} else {
console.log("added a food");
}
});
});

}

var data = [
{ 
name: "Avocados",
easyFood: true,
phase1: true,
about: "Yum Avocados",
},

{ 
name: "Milk",
easyFood: true,
phase1: true,
about: "Yum Milk",
},
]

module.exports = seedfoods;
```

Comment: **Option 1 :** Use separate app to put data into your database. **Option 2 :** Check condition whether we already have data on the database

Comment: I tried  name:   { type: String, required: false, unique: true }, and it works but it will obviously throw duplicate errors every single time. Which seems bad.

Comment: You can check the 'count' of your collection. If it's 0, seed, otherwise completely skip.

Comment: Like this? Food.count([], function (err, count) {
      console.log(count);
    });

Comment: Yes, then save count in a var. Afterwards, if that var === 0, seed.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply seed your mongoDB using `mongoimport` outside of your app. This way your app doesn't have to worry about seeding - useful when your collections are not coupled.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

Have an initial script on the start of the server which runs the seed once and stores some sort of record of doing so (e.g. a db entry or a file or something similiar). This is probably the cleanest, but also the one with the biggest effort.

What I suggest you do is this: You can skip the detection of existing documents by simply using the upsert option in an update query, which will only create a new document, if it doesn't exist already. So just run your seed on every start with an update operation with the option `{upsert: true}`.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate